# Is there a way to clear the cache in the administration?

Tags: administrator, cache

I made a change to an admin component, but it's not reflected immediately.  Is there a way to make the admin cache refresh?  I know with modules you can set cache to none, but this is a component so I don't have that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It is called [**Cache Cleaner**](http://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/cachecleaner), extension from Regular Labs (ex-NoNumber).

With Cache Cleaner you can clean your cache fast and easily via a link in your Joomla! Administrator.

Not only that, it also gives you the possibility to purge expired cache, do a global check-in, empty the temp folder, empty user-defined folders and database tables … all with just 1 click!

Cache Cleaner can clean your cache automatically when you save an article or other item. And it can clean your cache at preset intervals too.
So no more clickety-click to get to the core Joomla! Cache Manager and no more manually deleting files.

Let it be noted that the **extension cleans up both /cache folders** (site's and admin's), even though that is not explicitely written in description.

I have been using it for ages and can't imagine my work in Joomla admin without it.
HIGHLY RECOMMENDED!

Comment: Ah I have this installed but I did not know this.  Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Login to admin panel, see top menu, click "System", click sub menu "Clear Cache", I think rest you will understand.

Comment: I thought that was for the front end only?  I want to clear the cache in the back end.

Comment: Hi,  

I think joomla doesn't store different cached file for site or admin part, are you facing any issue? Write specific, maybe can suggest something based on your feedback.

Comment: Yes, I am facing the issue I described.  I have updated the CSS on an admin component and the change is not immediately reflected.  Thus I assume cache is the issue as the change does get reflected after a while.  I think the cache cleaner option is the best one.  Joomla! must store different admin cache.  When you clear cache using the normal Regular Labs Cache Cleaner it only lists front end files.  Also there is a folder administrator/cache and also a cache folder in the site root suggesting your assessment may be incorrect.